# Excess baggage for economical prepositioning (London/Denver)

Tags: luggage, london, luggage-storage, shipping, denver

I wanna ship camping gear to/from London/Denver in August/sept rather rent/leave there - don't know where I'll be staying yet - I would like to ship and have in place 2 weeks before I leave (unreliable shipping companies).

Has anyone done this before? Anglo Pacific / sendmybag will ship wherever but can't give any advice where I could ship to.

Update - from the comments - apparently what I want is called 'Poste Restante' in the UK. In the USA it's known as [General Delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poste_restante#United_States) - however I'm more thinking of a shipping company like UPS/Fedex/doddle.

Replying to comments :

I looked at renting but it would be $500 for the week - could buy at that price.

I think what I'd do is buy the lot from a US online retailer have it delivered somewhere I could drive to and pickup when I arrived.

Comment: [Poste restante](https://www.postoffice.co.uk/mail/poste-restante)?

Comment: Or [General Delivery](https://faq.usps.com/s/article/What-is-General-Delivery) if you're shipping to the US (it's not clear from your question whether you need to ship to Denver, London, or both.)

Comment: Go to an official camping for first few days (which you will use to buy the fresh things and beverages [and for jet-lag]). Ask them if you can send in advance some parcels.

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question. But why don't you just rent it? We have lots of sporting goods/outdoor retailers here in Denver that rent equipment. I've done it before, and it's pretty painless.

Comment: How much gear do you propose to bring?! Why aren't you just bringing it in checked luggage? I have some ideas but it really depends on how much stuff it is.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Exactly. And even if checked luggage is more expensive (which I doubt), it's so much more convenient.

Comment: I initially read the question as "economical propositioning", which would have put a whole new spin on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For UPS/Fedex, you can use [Hold for Pickup](https://www.ups.com/us/en/shipping/services/value-added/hold-for-pickup.page)/[Hold at Location](https://www.fedex.com/en-us/service-guide/pickup-delivery.html) services. The shipping company will hold the package at their depot (which may be in an out-of-the-way location) or a retail store for a limited number of days. You won't be able to have them hold it for two weeks though: UPS is "five days" while FedEx is "5 business days." This is an option if you ship the items yourself, but is not always an option when purchasing from online retailers.

You might also find a campsite or hotel willing to accept and hold your package for you, and you could start your trip there.

In some locations, [Amazon Locker](https://www.amazon.com/primeinsider/tips/amazon-locker-qa.html) service could work, if there's one nearby.

As others have noted, checking the items on your flight is still likely to be the cheapest option.

Comment: Thanks for the info - https://www.norwegian.com/uk/travel-info/baggage/sports-equipment/ - cost of baggage across the atlantic is crazy - £9 per kg both ways - I'll most likely just buy the gear in USA - traveling with daughter so need a big 2 room tent.

Comment: @bryanhunt That fee is only for overweight items. The cost is [lower](https://www.norwegian.com/uk/booking/booking-information/optional-charges/#Baggage_allowances) (but varies based on a complicated table) for ordinary checked bags.